# Can the following warning cause any problem in the future in my JOGL (JogAmp) application?

Tags: java, jogl

My Java OpenGL (JogAmp) program works without problems, but I get these warnings:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred  
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3 (file:/C:/Users/HAL%209000/Desktop/Szoveges/Java%202019/JOGL%20(jogamp)/gluegen.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)  
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3  
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations  
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

It happens since I reinstalled Windows 7.
Java version I use:
Java 8 (64bit)
Java Developement Kit 11.0.2 (64bit)

I suspect the new Java is not compatible with my JogAmp.
I downloaded the newest JogAmp, but I still get the warnings.

I am worried my program will stop working in the future. Could it happen? Is there any way to fix this issue? Or can I ignore these warning, because my program works just fine?

I found online that other people have this problem too, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: The final line of the warning seems to answer your question.

Comment: It's already fixed in a separate branch whose content will be put into JOGL 2.5 or 3.0 and actually, I'd like the particular change fixing this warning to be done right now in JOGL 2.4 that will be released in a few weeks or months. It's not very important as it allowed to use the extension mechanism which disappeared from Java since the version 9.

Comment: I advise you to look at this bug report: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1363#c3 Moreover, rather ask JOGL specific questions on the most appropriate places, i.e our official forum http://forum.jogamp.org and our bug tracker, as numerous JOGL maintainers aren't on SO and we prefer avoiding the risk of FUD campaigns by talking about our stuff where we feel comfortable with wise moderators (including me ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

One commenter said it was fixed in 2.4, but unfortunately it looks like 2.3.2 is still the current version of JOGL. I got rid of this error message by setting both my JDK and JRE (execution environment) to Java 1.8.  Just setting Java compliance to 1.8 was not sufficient.